# Django 4.1 Google Social Auth does not authenticate

Tags: django, django-socialauth

I am not sure what happened as this was working fine before.
Now, when I use google authentication with social-auth, and when I check request.user.is_authenticated, it is always False.
I will provide my setup, I checked it hundreds of times, I just can't seem to see the error:

Here are the variable to my key files. I verified the keys, I can confirm I am using the correct ones, I changed the URI and got an error.
Here are all my settings. I use the login_view to create a userProfile and to send out emails. All this was working fine, and I have no idea why it would just stop.
This is all happening on a local Dev server I have on an Ubuntu VM.

Please, if you have any suggestions at all, I would be so very happy.

```
# social auth configs for google
SOCIAL_AUTH_GOOGLE_OAUTH2_KEY = os.environ.get('SOCIAL_AUTH_GOOGLE_OAUTH2_KEY')
SOCIAL_AUTH_GOOGLE_OAUTH2_SECRET = os.environ.get(
    'SOCIAL_AUTH_GOOGLE_OAUTH2_SECRET')
SOCIAL_AUTH_GOOGLE_OAUTH2_SCOPE = [
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email',
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile'
]

#installed apps:
'social_django',

#middleware:
'social_django.middleware.SocialAuthExceptionMiddleware',

#templates:
'social_django.context_processors.backends',
'social_django.context_processors.login_redirect',

AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    'social_core.backends.google.GoogleOAuth2',
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',

LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = "login_view"
SOCIAL_AUTH_LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = "login_view"

SOCIAL_AUTH_PIPELINE = (
    'social_core.pipeline.social_auth.social_details',
    'social_core.pipeline.social_auth.social_uid',
    'social_core.pipeline.social_auth.auth_allowed',
    'social_core.pipeline.social_auth.social_user',
    'Quiz.pipeline.redirect_to_login_view',  # custom pipeline function
    'social_core.pipeline.user.get_username',
    'social_core.pipeline.user.create_user',
    'social_core.pipeline.social_auth.associate_user',
    'social_core.pipeline.social_auth.load_extra_data',
    'social_core.pipeline.user.user_details',
)

pipeline.py:
from django.shortcuts import redirect


def redirect_to_login_view(strategy, details, user=None, *args, **kwargs):
    redirect_url = '/login_view/'
    return redirect(redirect_url)
```

Comment: Ok, I disabled the pipeline that was suppose to get the login_view executed. So now the Google login works BUT I need to get to the login_view, and both my redirects don't do anything:
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = "login_view"
SOCIAL_AUTH_LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = "login_view"
Do you guys how I can get my view executed?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I was talking to myself here, lol. Sometimes it helps just to talk things thru:

Here is how I fixed it:

```
 <a class="btn btn-outline-danger w-100" href="{% url 'social-auth:begin' 'google-oauth2' %}?next=/login_view/">
```

The next=/login_view/ is what saved my day.
Sorry for the ramble and to whomever read all this.